# How to update GCP Scheduler Jobs with Python

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-scheduler

I'm working in this project to automate updates in Cloud Scheduler Jobs with Python.

I already wrote the logic in Python but I'm facing one problem, it looks like that to update a Cloud Scheduler job with Python is similar to create a job, you have to past most of the properties of the job in the code, that is the problem, I only want to update the `retry_config`, nothing else. I want to leave the `schedule` and the `target` as it is, so I don't have to past those again every time.

Of course I can get the current `schedule` and `target` of the job using another class as `GetJobRequest` for example, that wouldn't be a problem, but I wish I didn't have to, since I don't want to update those fields.

Help?

```
from google.cloud import scheduler_v1
from google.protobuf import duration_pb2

client = scheduler_v1.CloudSchedulerClient()

retry_config = scheduler_v1.RetryConfig()
retry_config.retry_count = 4
retry_config.max_doublings = 4
retry_config.min_backoff_duration = duration_pb2.Duration(seconds=5)
retry_config.max_backoff_duration = duration_pb2.Duration(seconds=60)

job = scheduler_v1.Job()
job.name = f"projects/{PROJECT_ID}/locations/{DATAFLOW_REGION}/jobs/test"
job.retry_config = retry_config
job.schedule = "* * * * 1"

method = scheduler_v1.HttpMethod(2)

target = scheduler_v1.HttpTarget()
target.uri = "https://xxxx"
target.http_method = method

job.http_target = target

request = scheduler_v1.UpdateJobRequest(
    job=job
)

response = client.update_job(request=request)

print(response)
```

Comment: You should be able to define an `update_mask` in which you define the fields that you want to change. The `job` need then only contain those fields. See [UpdateJobRequest](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/cloudscheduler/latest/google.cloud.scheduler_v1.types.UpdateJobRequest)

Comment: The underlying method call is [`projects.locations.jobs.patch`](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.jobs/patch) which provides more of an explanation.

Comment: Unfortunately, documentation for **update_mask** is hard to find. The library source is published, so dig into the source code. 1) `from google.protobuf import field_mask_pb2` 2) Update Mask looks like this: `update_mask = field_mask_pb2.FieldMask(paths=['description','schedule']`

Comment: It worked @DazWilkin and @JohnHanley. I added the lines `from google.protobuf import field_mask_pb2`, `update_mask = field_mask_pb2.FieldMask(paths=['retry_config'])` and `request = scheduler_v1.UpdateJobRequest(job=job, update_mask=update_mask )`. Thanks!

Comment: Please post an answer with your solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to specify the properties that need to be changed using the `update_mask` parameter.

The final code will be as follows:

```
from google.cloud import scheduler_v1
from google.protobuf import duration_pb2, field_mask_pb2

client = scheduler_v1.CloudSchedulerClient()

retry_config = scheduler_v1.RetryConfig()
retry_config.retry_count = 4
retry_config.max_doublings = 4
retry_config.min_backoff_duration = duration_pb2.Duration(seconds=5)
retry_config.max_backoff_duration = duration_pb2.Duration(seconds=60)

job = scheduler_v1.Job()
job.name = f"projects/{PROJECT_ID}/locations/{DATAFLOW_REGION}/jobs/test"
job.retry_config = retry_config

update_mask = field_mask_pb2.FieldMask(paths=['retry_config'])

request = scheduler_v1.UpdateJobRequest(
    job=job,
    update_mask=update_mask
)

response = client.update_job(request=request)

print(response)
```